# How can I move the TrackBar in response to mouse events in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mousemove, trackbar

This is probably a n00b query. I have a need where I want to change the trackbar value based on a mouse down event. This I achieved as follows:

```
private void MoveTrackBarToMouseClickLocation(TrackBar a_tBar, int a_mouseX)
{
    // Jump to the clicked location

        double dblValue;
        dblValue = ((double)a_mouseX / (double)a_tBar.Width) * (a_tBar.Maximum -    a_tBar.Minimum);
        a_tBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(dblValue);
}
```

That part works fine. I am having trouble getting the scroll working while the mouse button is pressed. e.g. If I click on the trackbar and it takes me to say value 50 with the mouse down, I want to be able to scroll right or left (from value=50) while that mouse is down.

I hope I have made my small issue clear.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to execute your code in the [`MouseMove` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx), as well as the `MouseDown` event.**

This event occurs when the mouse is moved *while* one of the buttons is held down. In contrast, the `MouseDown` event that you currently handle only gets raised once each time the mouse button is pressed down. That's why the `TrackBar` is not moving when the user moves the mouse, but is working properly the first time the button is pressed.

You didn't show the code where you wired up the event handlers and/or call the `MoveTrackBarToMouseClickLocation` function, so that's as specific as I can get. But if you managed to wire up the `MouseDown` event already, this should be a simple fix.

Comment: Yes, I have already hooked the mouse down event, the MoveTrackBartoMouseClickedLocation() is called in the mouse down event handler...